# How to count variable values' frequency in SAS

Tags: count, sas, frequency

Here is the data I have:

```
ID VALUE
1    1
2   -1
3    1
4    1
5    1
1    1
2    1
3   -1
4    1
5   -1
...
```

How can I get a table like this:

```
ID value=1  value=-1
1    2         0 
2    1         1
3    1         1
4    2         0
5    1         1
```

`value=1` means how many time `1` appears in the value column for each ID

Answer (score 1):

```
data work.indata    ;
input ID VALUE;
cards;  
1    1
2   -1
3    1
4    1
5    1
1    1
2    1
3   -1
4    1
5   -1
;
run;

/*    
proc sort data=work.indata;
by ID;
run;
*/

proc freq noprint data=work.indata;
tables ID * VALUE /out=WORK.COUNTS nopercent ;
run;


proc transpose data=WORK.COUNTS out=work.output (drop=_name_ _label_);
id value;
by id;
var count;
run;
```

Comment: You do not need that proc sort.